# Why does mashing jump let the player jump twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where if the player mashes the jump button fast enough, they get an extra jump.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with my implementation of coyote time since it's letting the player jump even when slightly off the ground, but I'm not sure how I could change it to fix this issue without removing the mechanic entirely.

Here's the code I'm using for jumping.

```
    //Check if player is grounded
    IsGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(GroundCheck.position, 0.1f, GroundLayer);


    //Coyote Jump
    if (IsGrounded == true)
    {
        HangCount = HangTime;
    }
    else if(IsGrounded == false)
    {
        HangCount -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    //Jump Buffer
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        JumpBufferCount = JumpBufferLength;
    }
    else
    {
        JumpBufferCount -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    //Jump
    if (JumpBufferCount >= 0 && HangCount > 0)
    {
        RB.velocity = new Vector2(RB.velocity.x, JumpHeight);
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Jump");
        HangCount = 0;
        JumpBufferCount = 0;
    }

 
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe after the first jump you are still close enough to the floor so that the `OverlapCircle` still returns true and allows a second jump?

Comment: Just tried fixing it like this. It didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Well the only thing that can happen is that the `HangCount` for some reason is bigger than 0 (the JumpBufferCount is anyway since you hit the jump button) .. and the only place where I see the HangCount possibly increasing is if isGrounded is true ... Maybe you should add a cooldown for the jump button itself?

Comment: Never mind. I found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I just added a check to see if my Y velocity was equal to or less than 0 so the player couldn't jump while already ascending.